# Selenium IDE: Target the second occurence of a span element that contains a specific string

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-ide

Creating a testing script using Selenium IDE. I'm creating an extension for the Magento eCommerce platform. I need to target a sub-menu item that will contain the string "Dashboard". These menu items are contained in span elements. Normally I would just use the following:

```
css=span:contains('Dashboard')
```

However Magento already contains 1 instance of this by default. I need a way to specify the second (or last) occurence of a span element that contains the word *Dashboard*. I have to make use of a relative term like "last" in order to select it due to the variance of Magento menus across installs and versions. That means I can't use nth selectors or anything like that. Any help would be appreciated.

**Rendered HTML that might be usable for targeting:**

```
<li class="  parent level0">
<a href="#" class=""><span>My Menu</span></a>
<ul >
<li  class="  last level1"> <a href="/link"   class=""><span>Dashboard</span></a>
```

**Verbal way to target my specific span:**

"First span to contain the text 'Dashboard' after span containing the text 'My Menu'"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("...")
count = len(elements)
lastElement = elements[count - 1]
```

OR go for the last element only:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.last level1>a>span")
```